# passing param to a controller must be instance error

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a jquery post coupon value to a controller

```
 $.post(url,{coupon:coupon},function(obj)
```

below is the constructor method

```
namespace Lti\QuickID\Controller\Index;

class verify extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_date;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;       
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
){

    $this->_date = $date;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){

    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

    $params         = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $coupon = $params['coupon'];

    ........

    return $result->setData([
                "error" => $error,
                "response" => $msg,
                'quickid' => $coupon]);
}
```

I have verified that $post is passing correct value

whenever I do di:compile and static-content:deploy, passing value to controller give following error

```
Argument 1 passed to L__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given
```

the problem occur in both production and developer mode, and can be fixed by doing rm -rf var/di/*

my question is why this is happening?

Comment: can you paste complete controller code looks like it has issue in class extends ?

Comment: my bad, the complete code is long I didn't want to overwhelm you with unnecessary data, looks like I removed too much, I added more code now

Comment: This code has no error there is some other file which has this issue . and please follow naming convention make class name Verify not  verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have tested this and it works fine for me.

**app/code/Vendor/Package/Controller/Index/Verify.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Package\Controller\Index;

class Verify extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_date;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_date = $date;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $coupon = $params['coupon'];
        $error = '';
        $msg ='';

        return $result->setData([
            "error" => $error,
            "response" => $msg,
            'quickid' => $coupon]);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Package/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="verify" frontName="verify">
            <module name="Vendor_Package" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Package/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Package" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Package/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Package',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now run the following:

1. bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Package; bin/magento setup:upgrade; bin/magento setup:di:compile;

To access this endpoint: www.yourdomain.test/verify/index/verify .

Comment: I actually tried both ways, having parent constructor at first and at the end, same result

Comment: try removing , `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` and compile agian.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change signature of a constructor for a class magento  needs to regenerate the classes, which can be done by removing var/di and var/generation for 2.1 and for 2.2 var/di and generated folder located at root.

You can look into why magento does code generation here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html